# Unable to call custom methods within extended Magento model

Tags: magento, overriding

I'm attempting to customize the way pricing / tiered pricing is displayed in Magento CE 1.6.0.0.

I've followed the instructions in the second post of the link below to override Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16829/

Following is my custom model class:

```
class PHC_Price_Model_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price {
    public function getPrice() {
        echo "overridden getPrice method called<br>";
    }

    public function getPHCDisplayPrice($product) {
        echo "custom price function called<br>";
    }
}
```

I'm able to successfully call the overridden getPrice() function from my template file as follows:

```
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->entity_id);
$displayPrice = $product->getPrice();
```

However, when I try to call my custom price function with

```
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->entity_id);
$displayPrice = $product->getPHCDisplayPrice();
```

I get absolutely nothing. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It't normal that you don't get a result. I would be amazed if this worked.

You are overriding the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`, but in your example the `$product` variable is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`. That class does not have the method `getPHCDisplayPrice` and it calls the `__call` method and returns null.

You get the expected result when calling `getPrice` by accident. It is because the `getPrice` method in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` looks like this:

```
public function getPrice()
{
    if ($this->_calculatePrice || !$this->getData('price')) {
        return $this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this);
    } else {
        return $this->getData('price');
    }
}
```

So when you call it, it calls `$this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this)` and `$this->getPriceModel()` returns an instance of your class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - it's nice to understand what was happening. I was able to accomplish what I needed by extending Mage_Catalog_Model_Product instead.